# Copy & replace/insert loads of data from CSV file located on Google Drive to SpreadSheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I fetch data from another service to Google Drive. Its format is CSV and being saved in .csv on Google Drive. The size for each file around 5MB and >17K rows!. I tried to use Import script but it didn't work, it worked with smaller file but I just want to copy the whole csv to my spreadsheet without caring about old data.

```js
function import() {
   var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById("****"); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('report.csv'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***"); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "report.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
        for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
    /*
    ** report data is now in 'NEWDATA' sheet in the spreadsheet - process it as needed,
    ** then delete 'NEWDATA' sheet using ss.deleteSheet(newsheet)
    */
    // rename the report.csv file so it is not processed on next scheduled run
   // file.setName("report-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv");
  }
};
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work, which line does it fail at? where is CSVToArray?

Comment: CSVToArray is a function which I didn't include. It simply a copy from google.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your script is probably timing out if it is processing that many lines. Few things you can do to optimise your code:

- Replace CSVToArray() with the built-in Utilities.parseCsv() function.
- Move the getRange().setValues() out of the loop, write everything to an array and then write that to the sheet in one call.
- If it is still too slow look at the [Continuous Batch Library](http://patt0.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/continuous-batch-library-update-for.html) which will allow you to break up the processing into smaller chunks

Comment: Utilities.parseCsv()  worked wonderful. Thank you for your suggestion Andrew.